# Can AWS Glue Job write to SAP HANA?

Tags: aws-glue, hana

I can find sources on AWS and elsewhere on JDBC Connection to SAP Hana via AWS Glue. Is writing to Hana also possible - say via CDATA JDBC Driver?

Can someone point to a source for the write capability? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is entirely possible. You can create [custom connectors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/connectors-chapter.html#creating-custom-connectors), that will allow you to read and write to HANA.

In addition, there is already a [connector](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B08PG582C8?ref_=beagle&applicationId=GlueStudio) on the AWS Marketplace for HANA, which you can use.

Comment: So CDATA is bidirectional? I was not sure of that.

Comment: Yes, it is. Connectors can be Data Sinks since a couple of days. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/aws-announces-data-sink-capability-for-the-glue-connectors/